# Liferay AWS EC2 instance selection

Tags: amazon-ec2, liferay-6

I am just exploring AWS for hosting Liferay 6.2. What is the decent EC2 instance type I should select considering 2GB Heap space allocated to Liferay and 10 concurrent users.

I started to evaluate free micro tier and Liferay does not startup obviously because 1GB is not enough.

I don't want to go and create each instance type in increasing order of power and then terminate. So if somebody has already done something similar and could recommend a starting EC2 instance type will be helpful.

Comment: I'm not sure this question is really on topic here.  With any application, there is no simple answer -- you have to observe performance metrics and go from there.  Intuitively, I'd say a t2.medium (4GB) might be on the low end of "adequate" for light traffic, and t2.large (8GB) otherwise.

Comment: Makes sense, but the number of options aws provides confuses me. I read somewhere that sometimes with lot of options people tend to make wrong decision with AWS. For example in t2.medium/large there are these Credits alloted. Does it really make sense for Liferay Server or not is tough decision. Thanks for the feedback though.

Comment: If you find a server is too large or to small, you stop it, change its instance type, and restart it.  Within the same instance class, and often within the same family, it's essentially that simple.  There is no need to get it perfect the first time.